# Increasing the numbers of I/O pins on Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno

I want to make a game of [Tic-tac-toe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe) using an Arduino, LEDs and bouncy buttons. Hence I need nine inputs and nine outputs. But you see that an Arduino only has 13 I/O pins. So is there a way I can use the analog pins or a way to reduce the number of I/O pins using an ingenious way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to have more than 14 Output pins on arduino?](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/117/is-there-a-way-to-have-more-than-14-output-pins-on-arduino)

Comment: See [Is there a way to have more than 14 Output pins on arduino?](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/117/is-there-a-way-to-have-more-than-14-output-pins-on-arduino/13248#13248) - there is a lengthy discussion there, with references.

Comment: I added [an answer](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/14436/3917) to the question Nick mentioned, with a note about accessing 7 I/O lines from the Atmega16U2 on the Uno.

Comment: Have a look at [charlieplexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlieplexing)

Comment: This question is similar to [Creating an Arduino Tic Tac Toe game](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/23542/19409).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, just use the analog pins. The analog pins are both analog inputs and digital I/O pins. The functions happen to be shared on the pins, in the same way that the interrupt pins are shared with digital I/O, the TX and RX pins are shared with digital I/O and the SPI pins are shared with digital I/O.

Every I/O pin (analog or digital, etc.) can be used as digital I/O.

You can also reduce your required number of I/O pins by using a technique known as *multiplexing*.

For instance, to read nine buttons you could have them arranged (as in Tic-tac-toe) in three rows of three buttons. You then have three I/O pins for the columns and three I/O pins for the rows - that's just six I/O pins for nine buttons.

The technique is widely used for keypads, but they are just buttons, so the same technique can be applied to any buttons.

- *[The Matrix Keypad how-to](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/KeypadTutorial)*

The same can go for LEDs. There are various specialist LED multiplexing techniques that allow for many LEDs to be driven from just a handful of I/O pins.

- *[How to Multiplex an LED Grid...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MmCGDJ90Qt4)* (YouTube)
- *[Charlieplex Library for Arduino](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Charlieplex)*

Comment: You can also multiplex buttons with LEDs, this way you just need 3 pins for commons + 3 pins for LEDs + 3 pins for inputs.

Answer (score 2):

If multiplexing is too complicated for you, you can wire all buttons to one analog pin using resistors. This way you only need 9 pins for LEDs and 1 analog pin for buttons.

[image]

Comment: What I am planning to do is that use rgb leds, So if user 1 presses some button then red color and then next one green. So I guess that this method would not be able to work that way, because they require different voltages. And all this process have to be dynamic. I don't know which button will the user be pressing.